# Minimal size of generators for $PSL(3,2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is known that the simple group $PSL(3,2)$ of order $168$ can be generated by $2$ elements. In fact, every finite simple group can be generated by $2$ elements. I am looking for an example of such a pair of generators. So far, I did not find it in the literature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a subgroup of $S_7$ it is generated (for example) by $(4,6)(5,7)$ and $(1,2,4)(3,6,5)$.

It can also be defined by the nice  $2$-generator presentation

$$\langle x,y \mid x^2=y^3=(xy)^7=[x,y]^4=1 \rangle.$$

```
[1 1 0]
[0 1 0]
[0 0 1]

[0 0 1]
[1 0 0]
[0 1 0]
```

Comment: See edited post for matrix generators. You could use GAP for questions like this.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. The question was closed today, after $7$ years. Why? The level seems not so bad indeed (or was not considered so for several years). Is there something more about it?

Comment: Very strange! I've voted to reopen. Tempus fugit.